Show multivariate version of Slutsky's theorem: $Z_nX_n\overset{d}{\to}AX$
Let $Z_n$ be a $(d \times d)$-probability matrix and $A$ be a $(d \times d)$-constant matrix.
If $X_n\overset{d}{\to}X$ and $Z_n\overset{p}{\to}A$, then $Z_nX_n\overset{d}{\to}AX.$
my attempt
If $A$ were a constant in one dimension, it could be proved immediately by the continuous mapping theorem, but the fact that it is multidimensional is troublesome, and I can't seem to get around to it.
What kind of work can I do to show it successfully?

You can show that $(X_n, Z_n) \to_{d} (X, A)$. Then $Z_nX_n \to_{d} AX$ by continuous mapping.

I'll write it out in detail, a lot of which can be viewed as obvious.
Now apply Skorokhod's Representation Theorem to find a Probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and random variables $X_{n}'$  and $X'$ such that $X_{n}'\xrightarrow{a.s.}X'$ and $X_{n}'=X_{n}$ in distribution and $X=X'$ in distribution.
Now consider $n_{k}$ to be an arbitrary subsequence and find a further subsequence such that $Z_{n_{k_{l}}}\xrightarrow{a.s.}A$. (Convergence in probability implies convergence almost surely along a subsequence).
Thus, given any subsequence, there exists a further subsequence such that $(X'_{n_{k_{l}}},Z_{n_{k_{l}}})\xrightarrow{a.s.}(X',A)$.
This is enough for convergence in distribution, i.e. $(X_{n},Z_{n})\xrightarrow{d}(X,A)$
So, we can simplify notation and assume that $(X_{n},Z_{n})\xrightarrow{a.s.}(X,A)$ in some particular probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$.
Now, see that the $ij$-th entry of $Z_{n}X_{n}$ is $\sum_{k=1}^{d}z_{ik}^{n}x^{n}_{kj}$. But for each $k$, you have $z^{n}_{ik}x^{n}_{kj}\xrightarrow{a.s.}a_{ik}x_{kj}$
So, $\sum_{k=1}^{d}z_{ik}^{n}x^{n}_{kj}\xrightarrow{a.s.}\sum_{k=1}^{d}a_{ik}x_{kj}$. And this happens for all $i,j$. Thus each entry of the matrix $Z_{n}X_{n}$ converges almost surely to $AX$ and hence $Z_{n}X_{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}AX$
This holds for some particular probability space. But that is enough to show $Z_{n}X_{n}\xrightarrow{d}AX$
NOTE: The crux of the argument is the fact that convergence in distribution can be characterized in the following way. $X_{n}\xrightarrow{d}X$ if and only if there exists a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and random variables (metric space valued) $X_{n}'$ and $X'$ such that $X_{n}'\xrightarrow{a.s.}X'$ and $X_{n}'=X_{n}$ in distribution and $X=X'$ in distribution. This is what Skorokhod's Theorem is actually saying.
We are coupling that with the fact that $X_{n}\xrightarrow{d}X$ if and only if given any subsequence $X_{n_{k}}$, there exists a further subsequence $X_{n_{k_{l}}}$ such that $X_{n_{k_{l}}}\xrightarrow{d}X$.
Otherwise, after one gets $(X_{n},Z_{n})\xrightarrow{d}(X,A)$, one can view matrix multiplication as a continuous function from $M_{d}(\Bbb{R})\times M_{d}(\Bbb{R})\to M_{d}(\Bbb{R})$ equipped with any norm (all norms are equivalent in finite dimensional spaces) and then use continuous mapping theorem.
